# Build.Gradle error: Unable to resolve dependency

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

when i was going to sync gradle in my android studio project i got these errors. prviousy i added 3 images to the drawable folder with the names **img2,img3,img4** .

**Error images:**

[image: the error images]

I also have successfully installed the

1. ConstraintLyaout for Android
2. Solver for constraintLayout

As they were mentioned as most common reason for these type of errors .
Thank you very much in advance .

Comment: Change 'junit:junit:img4.12.' to 'junit:junit:4.12.' in your gradle file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding img2, img3, and img4 you've accidentaly changed dependencies in your build.gradle file that contained 2, 3 or 4 digit. Change

```
 'junit:junit:img4.12.'
```

to

```
 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

and so on in every other dependency containing 'img' string.

Comment: @dinithjayabodhi if it worked then give muminers its credit .. accept this answer or upvote it

Comment: i tried to upvote it but it says as my score is less than 10 i can't upvote it ....i am really sorry